# PHP get sum of quantity inside a foreach to use it on for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, sum

im trying to get the total quantity

```
    The data from array would look like this;
    [desc]  [quantity]
    [foo1], [   2    ]
    [foo2], [   2    ]
....
```

This is the "code":

```
    function saveInvoiceDetail(array $wreceipt_items, $warehouse = '', $tracking = ''){
    global $con;

    $y = 0;

    foreach ($wreceipt_items as $wreceipt_item){
        $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['desc'] ) );
        $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['quantity'] ) );

        $query = "INSERT INTO wreceipt_items (`id`, `warehouse`, `desc`, `quantity`)
                VALUES (NULL, '$warehouse', '$desc', '$quantity')";
    $y++;
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
    }

$quantity_sum = array_sum($wreceipt_item['quantity'])

    $x = $quantity_sum; //repeat this insert ($quantity_sum) times
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++){
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO control (`id`, `warehouse`, `tracking`)
                VALUES ('', '$warehouse-$i', '$tracking')";
            mysqli_query($con, $query2);
    }

}
```

Desired result: execute '$query2' X times, where X = $quantity_sum;
Can this be possible? I cant figure it out.

Note: the 'foreach' & 'for' works but i cant use the 'for' without the 'quantity sum'

**EDIT** - **FIXED**

```
function saveInvoiceDetail(array $wreceipt_items, $warehouse = '', $tracking = ''){
    global $con;

    $y = 0;

    foreach ($wreceipt_items as $wreceipt_item){
        $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['desc'] ) );
        $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['quantity'] ) );

        $query = "INSERT INTO wreceipt_items (`id`, `warehouse`, `desc`, `quantity`)
                VALUES (NULL, '$warehouse', '$desc', '$quantity')";
    $y++;
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
    }

$quantity_sum = array_sum(array_column($wreceipt_items, 'quantity'));

    $x = $quantity_sum; //repeat this insert ($quantity_sum) times
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++){
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO control (`id`, `warehouse`, `tracking`)
                VALUES ('', '$warehouse-$i', '$tracking')";
            mysqli_query($con, $query2);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the question? You've stated the desired result and then stated that your code already works. Why would you want to "user the 'for' without the `quantity sum`" if your stated goal is to execute $query2 a number of times equal to `quantity sum`? That is illogical!

Comment: I want to sum the value of quantity from array to execute the 'for' statement. Because i need to insert info into table that number of times. (Query2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract all the `quantity` values from `$wreceipt_items` and sum them:

```
$quantity_sum = array_sum(array_column($wreceipt_items, 'quantity'));
```

Comment: @IrvıngNgr' Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?